# server errors - heroku, django

Tags: django, heroku

I got an H20 error after deploying my code and visiting the site. Here's the log:

```
2013-04-12T11:45:59.304354+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path=/ host=olp-website.herokuapp.com fwd="86.151.6.106" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

So I tried to check out the dynos:

```
heroku ps --app olp-website

    === web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn -c gunicorn.py.ini wsgi:application
    web.1: up 2013/04/12 12:46:21 (~ 1m ago)

heroku ps:restart --app olp-website

    Restarting processes... done

heroku ps --app olp-website

    === web: newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn -c gunicorn.py.ini wsgi:application
    web.1: starting 2013/04/12 12:48:42 (~ 6s ago)
```

And now receive a 500 internal server error:

```
2013-04-12T13:38:19.116492+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-04-12 13:38:19 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:28853 (2)
2013-04-12T13:38:19.115928+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-04-12 13:38:19 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 0.14.3
2013-04-12T13:38:19.116593+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-04-12 13:38:19 [2] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
2013-04-12T13:38:19.122714+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-04-12 13:38:19 [5] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5
2013-04-12T13:38:19.135537+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-04-12 13:38:19 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2013-04-12T13:38:19.129099+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-04-12 13:38:19 [6] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6
2013-04-12T13:38:19.140715+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-04-12 13:38:19 [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2013-04-12T13:38:19.393488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2013-04-12T13:38:20.310391+00:00 app[web.1]: 2013-04-12 13:38:20,310 (5/Dummy-2) newrelic.core.agent INFO - New Relic Python Agent (1.3.0.289)
2013-04-12T13:38:21.072892+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=olp-website.herokuapp.com fwd="86.151.6.106" dyno=web.1 connect=31ms service=761ms status=500 bytes=5
```

I can't see what's wrong because the code works fine in development, and I'm using the django-skel settings files for production.

Do you have an idea as to what might be set up incorrectly?

Edit: Just looking at the database information on heroku, it looks like the database has 0 tables - so I guess that the sqlite databse didn't migrate to postresql.

Answer (score 0):

The H20 error generally means that your app takes to long to boot after having been idle.

`The router will enqueue requests for 75 seconds while waiting for starting processes to reach an “up” state. If after 75 seconds, no web dynos have reached an “up” state, the router logs H20 and serves a standard error page.`

You must check if that assets are precompiled or if there are other things that might slow down app boot.

**Debugging Timeouts:**

One cause of request timeouts is an infinite loop in the code. Test locally and see if you can replicate the problem and fix the bug.

Another possibility is that you are trying to do some sort of long-running task inside your web process, such as:

```
Sending an email
Accessing a remote API 
Web scraping / crawling
Rendering an image or PDF
Heavy computation 
Heavy database usage (slow or numerous queries)
```

If so, you should move this heavy lifting into a background job which can run asynchronously from your web request.

Another class of timeouts occur when an external service used by your application is unavailable or overloaded. In this case, your web app is highly likely to timeout unless you move the work to the background. In some cases where you must process these requests during your web request, you should always plan for the failure case.

Comment: The static assets have been compressed and uploaded to Amazon S3. It's only a really small app and works fine on my development server, so I can't think that there is a problem there. Could it be to do with the database (see my edit above)? Also, after restarting the dynos, the error changed to 500 internal server error.

Comment: There are many reasons of timeout. As you said about database, do you have infinite loop in the code?

Comment: Sending an email, Accessing a remote API (posting to Twitter, querying Flickr, etc.), Web scraping / crawling, Rendering an image or PDF, Heavy computation, Heavy database usage (slow or numerous queries)

Comment: Tested locally it seems fine. Is there a way to do a trackback on heroku? All I can see is heroku logs which doesn't give a trackback for the error.

Comment: In our site, we use getsentry to get the full traceback of errors